# Install python-matplotlib under Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib

I am having difficulty with the installation of python-matplotlib. When I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646179/how-to-install-python-matplotlib-in-ubuntu-12-04), and then try to type:

```
 cd matplotlib-matplotlib-bb3ea55
```

I get the following error:

```
bash: cd: matplotlib-matplotlib-bb3ea55: No such file or directory
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You made a lot of typos. `cd` command is for changing directories. And maplotlib-matplotlib-bb3ea55 is just... well i have no idea what that is ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pip` command.

```
sudo pip install matplotlib
```

If you don't have pip:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

-EDIT-
For python 3 change python-pip to python3-pip

Comment: Thank you. now  'No module named vis'

Comment: If my solution worked, please upvote it ;) What about 'No module named vis'? If `vis` is library, you should be able to install it using `pip`.